# Async await not working on html2pdf command

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to generate and save pdf. Then I am using fetch to get pdf data. Problem is that my await is not working on html2pdf() line. If I use settimeout on fetch then it's working correctly. Using await is giving me 404 error. Following is my code.

```js
(async () => {
  var element = document.getElementById('canvas_div_pdf');
  var opt = {
    pagebreak: { before: '.beforeClass' },
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
  };
  let pdfData;
  let timestamp = +new Date();

  await html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .toPdf()
    .get('pdf')
    .then(function (pdf) {
      var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
      // page numbers
      for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pdf.setPage(i);
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.setTextColor(150);
        pdf.text(
          'Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages,
          pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 30,
          pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 10
        );
      }
    })
    .save(timestamp + '.pdf');

  await fetch(timestamp + '.pdf')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
      pdfData = text;
    });

  const rawResponse = await fetch('api/pdf', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: pdfData,
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();
  console.log(content);
})();
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. It's client-side code, right? So how is `save` supposed to save it to the server so your `fetch` can get it back (which doesn't even make sense because you already have it locally)? It will generate a download prompt for the user, not save anything to the server.

Comment: It would make more sense to use `.output('blob')` instead of `.save()` and then both show a download prompt for the blob and send its data to the server if you want it there. (And stop mixing `.then` with `await`.)

Comment: Thanks for help. How can I access pdf data from Blob object? @CherryDT

Comment: Actually, our requirement is to use this application only on localhost. Using save() I was downloading file on specific folder(I changed download path on browser). Then using fetch I am getting pdf data. I want to send pdf data to API

Comment: Check out the [MDN docs for `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). Depending on your use case a different access method may make sense. For more info including how to turn them into a download prompt using `createObjectURL`, check [this article (under "Using Blobs")](https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/#8d38). For sending its contents to the server, you probably want to pass the blob directly as body, unless you need it in a multipart form-data, then you have to wrap it in a `File` and set it in a `FormData` field first.

Comment: About your localhost thing: Hm but this will never work because the user may decide to save it elsewhere or with a different name than expected, also you cannot know when the user will have actually completed the save. (Also, they may just abort it.) This is why your `await` doesn't work, because it won't await the download to complete (this is outside of the scope of a website to know/see) but only for its data to be prepared by the libary.

Answer (score 0):

I did not run this code but first idea You may try is to :

```js
const pdf = await html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).toPdf().get('pdf');

var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
// page numbers
for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
  pdf.setPage(i);
  pdf.setFontSize(10);
  pdf.setTextColor(150);
  pdf.text(
    'Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages,
    pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 30,
    pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 10
  );
}

pdf.save();
```

What I mean is that you use `await` and `then` together which will not work. What you should do is to have `async` used on promise and then operate on result.

Comment: Still it's not fetching generated pdf. Even I have matched file name and put await in-front of pdf.save()

Comment: the same goes for other methods with `.then`